# How to set infowindow for all markers in google map using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I created stop point markers for where truck stopped.But I need some help for open infowindow when clicked all stop point.

My js codes :

```
   var ImageStop  = '/images/StopPoint.gif';
   var infoWindowTrcukStop = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   var json = result.d;
   obj = JSON.parse(json);

     for (var i = 0; i < obj.length - 1; i++)

     {

       if(parseInt(obj[i].Speed)==0)
      {
       var LatLngStop = new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].Lat, obj[i].Lng);
       markerStopTruck = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: LatLngStop,
       draggable: true,
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
       map: map,
       title: 'Stopped Here',
       icon: ImageStop,

      });

        google.maps.event.addListener(markerStopTruck, 'click', function (e) {

        infoWindowTruckStop.setContent(this.title);
        infoWindowTruckStop.open(map, markerStopTruck);


        });

       markerStopTruck.setMap(map);
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

```
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length - 1; i++)  {
               if(parseInt(obj[i].Hiz)==0)  {
                var LatLngStop = new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].Lat, obj[i].Lng);
                              markerStopTruck= new google.maps.Marker({
                                  position: LatLngStop,
                                  draggable: true,
                                  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                  map: map,
                                  title: '',
                                  icon: ImageStop,
                              });
                              var content = 'Stop Here';
                              google.maps.event.addListener(markerStopTruck, 'click', (function 
                               (markerStopTruck, content, infoWindowTruckStop) {
                                  return function () {
                                      infoWindowTruckStop.setContent(content);
                                      infoWindowTruckStop.open(map, markerStopTruck);
                                  };
                              })(markerStopTruck, content, infoWindowTruckStop));


                              markerStopTruck.setMap(map);

                          }  }
```